# java program to print number in integer as shuffle

Tags: java, int, shuffle

Sorry if my question is not clear, lets say I have `int a = 1234;`.
How can I print as follows, for a number of any length?

`123
132
213
231
321
312`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you decide that only the first 3 digits are chosen?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: At least, show us how much effort you have done before asking this question :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad oh, I think we both know how much effort went in beforehand.

Comment: Its permutation not shuffle:)

Comment: its for any length, hi tried but not get the result when I post it, but now I got it, as below, thanks for ur time

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test  {
    private static void swap(int[] p, int i, int j) {
        int t= p[i];
        p[i]= p[j];
        p[j]= t;
        return;
    }
        private static boolean nextPerm(int[] p) { // need p.length > 1
        int n= p.length;
        int i= n;
        if (i-- < 1) return false;
        for(;;) {
            int ii= i--;
            if (p[i] < p[ii]) {
                int j= n;
                while (!(p[i] < p[--j]));
                swap(p, i, j);
                for (j= n; j > ii; swap(p, --j, ii++));
                return true;
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                for (int j= n; j > i; swap(p, --j, i++));
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 123;
        String s = "" + x;
        int n = s.length();
        int[] p = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            p[i] = i;
        }
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                System.out.print(s.charAt(p[i]));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        while (nextPerm(p));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

finally I found, below is the code,

```
class ShuffleNumber {
private static int[] a = {1,2,3};

private static void print(int[] a) {
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    System.out.print("  " + a[i]);
    System.out.println();
}

private static void shuffle(){
int[] b = (int[])a.clone();
for (int i = b.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    int j = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    int temp = b[j];
    b[j] = b[i];
    b[i] = temp;
}
print(b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        shuffle();
}
```

}

Comment: this shuffles but does not generate all permutations